# Is there any way we can draw svg path in NCL?

Tags: svg, bezier, ncl

I want to draw the Chinese words in NCL with the TTF font. 
I have converted the TTF fonts to svg paths. If I can find a way to draw the svg path in NCL, I think we can draw every word for all the languages, without any limitation.

The svg path data just as below:

d="M1204 1679h162v-677q273 140 510 307l100 -144q-216 -136 -610 -333v-735q0 -136 150 -136h140q144 0 162 136q18 126 32 328q88 -36 170 -64q-20 -190 -44 -324q-38 -228 -282 -228h-216q-274 0 -274 270v1600zM26 99q261 90 618 236v630h-576v148h576v562h162v-1922 h-162v415q-192 -78 -554 -227z"

I belive the tags M,h,v,z is simple. But how to deal with the tags q,c? How can we draw the Bezier curve?

Comment: you could always draw the curves using sufficiently lots of sufficiently short straight line segments

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Chinese text rather than English text for labels etc.?

Comment: yep, want to write Chinese character for labels.

Comment: I assume you looked at https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Support, so: did you remember to ask this in the most important place for NCL questions, too? (SO is always your last resort, after web searching, and asking on whatever support board/tracker the technology in question uses). It might be that Chinese text, as text, is possible so that you don't need to this SVG hack for instance, which the people who work on NCL should be able to explain to you quite easily.